# Mac Terminal: ts-loader, webpack, npm start issue: output is on same line

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

[image]

As you can see, the string "ts-loader: Using..." is on the same line as the percentage output. I ask myself: "Why is there no line break?"

Maybe someone of you had this issue, too and found a solution worth sharing it with us.

As wanted I added my configuration of my WebPack.

Here is my webpack.config.js file...

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const precss = require('precss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
const HappyPack = require('happypack');

module.exports = {
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty'
    },
    entry: [
        'babel-polyfill',
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'app.[hash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false,
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.json', '.less']
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-maps',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.less|css$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: 'less-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
                }, {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader' // compiles Less to CSS
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                loaders: [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=assets/[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
            }
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({hash: false, template: './index.hbs'}),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            test: /\.scss$/,
            debug: true,
            options: {
                postcss: function () {
                    return [precss, autoprefixer];
                },
                context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
                output: {
                    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
                }
            }
        }),
        new HappyPack({
            loaders: [{
                path: 'ts-loader',
                query: {happyPackMode: true}
            }
            ],
            threads: 6
        }),
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: what does your webpack config look like

Comment: Added config file.

Comment: What terminal app is that? Does it clear the line when a carriage return (`\r`) is written to it? What's the output of `echo -e "foo\rbar"`?

Comment: Output is "bar" on a new line. I used Fish, but I have the same issue in the native Mac terminal (bash). Unimportent if I am in Webstorm or directly in the terminal.

Comment: This sort of behaviour is typical when you have multiple processes outputting to the same terminal. Since you're using `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`, I think it's being caused by that.

Comment: Sounds logical. I think you are right and i will mark this one as resolved.